# 301 Реддирект в Opencart

Tags: php, redirect, opencart

Доброго времени суток. Кто встречался с похожей ситуацией, подскажите как настроить 301 редирект с

1. **http://мойсайт.ру/index.php?route=information/contact**

на

1. **http://мойсайт.ру/index.php?route=information/creator&form_id=46**.

Магазин написан на Opencart и вся загвоздка в том, что вторая ссылка - это созданная мной форма.

Comment: в .htaccess не работает разве?

Comment: 1. Никогда, никогда нельзя делать редиректы на уровне сервера - переезд приложения превращается в пытку. 2. Кто вообще сказал, что там будет апач, а не nginx, например?

Comment: ну единичные редиректы думаю не проблема перенести, а вот на счет сервера да, не уточнил, каюсь

Comment: Потом этих единичных проблем набирается такой ворох, что переезд заканчивается через неделю. Никогда - это вообще никогда.

Comment: Не спорю, если бы это был полноценный магазин, так делать не следует. Но именно в этом случае мне нужно именно редиректом и воспользоваться, т.к. я делаю тз, а это как раз один из пунктов)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> как настроить 301 редирект

Настроить - никак. Это опенкарт, который явно входит в 5% худшего ПО на свете.

Вам нужно похакать контроллер `/catalog/controller/information/contact.php`. Прямо в методе `index()`, в самом его начале написать примерно следующее:

```
$url = $this->url->link('information/creator', 'form_id=46');
$this->response->redirect($url, 301);
```

Насколько помню, `redirect()` сам обрубит дальнейшее выполнение скрипта.

Comment: Мне кажется ваш вариант почти удался, единственное в урл теперь передается адресс http://мойсайт.ру/index.php?route=information/creator&amp;form_id=46.

Comment: ну, я говорил, что хуже этой платформы что-то придумать сложно. попробуйте так сформировать url: `$url = $this->url->link('information/creator') . '&form_id=46';`

Comment: Благодарю, вопрос решен!